# java junit test case for the class

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, testcase

My program is as follows:

```
   import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MangoDemo
{

    public static void main(String[ ] args) throws FileNotFoundException
     {
        output();

      }

        public static void output() throws FileNotFoundException{
             char[] lineChar = null;

                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("src/input.txt"));
                while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
                    String line = scanner.nextLine();
                    //System.out.println(line);
                lineChar = line.toCharArray();
                    sortStringBubble (lineChar);
                     int n = lineChar.length-1;
                     System.out.print(lineChar[n--]);
                     for (;  n >=0;  n-- ) {
                       if(lineChar[n] != ',') {
                         System.out.print(",");
                         System.out.print(lineChar[n]);
                       }
                     }
                     System.out.println();

             }//end oof while loop
        }

      public static void sortStringBubble( char  x [ ] )
      {
            int j;
            boolean flag = true;  // will determine when the sort is finished
            char temp;

            while ( flag )
            {
                  flag = false;
                  for ( j = 0;  j < x.length - 1;  j++ )
                  {

                          if ( Character.toString(x[j]).compareToIgnoreCase( Character.toString(x[j+1]) ) > 0 )
                          {                                             // sorting in ascending order
                                      temp = x[j];
                                      x [j] = x [j+1];     // swapping here 
                                      x [j+1] = temp; 
                                      flag = true;
                           } 


                   } 
            } 
      } 
}
```

I have attempted making test case, and here it is:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;


public class MangoDemoTest {

    @Test
    public void testoutput() {
        MangoDemo m = new MangoDemo();
        char[] a = {'a','b','c'};
        assertEquals("Result: ","c,b,a",m.output());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSortStringBubble() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

}
```

I am absolute novice to this. I am getting an error as well. Is there no way where I can test output without giving a parameter to the output function?. Can anyone help please?

thanks

Comment: You need to post the error you are getting

Comment: Just a side note - since `output()` is static, you should be invoking it staticly from your test class - `MangoDemo.output()`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `void output()` method is declared to return `void`. That means it returns nothing. But in the below code you are expecting it to return `"c,b,a"`. Either you have to change the `output()` to return `String` like `String output()` or you check for side-effects i.e. any changes that output is performing in the method.

```
assertEquals("Result: ","c,b,a", m.output());
```

Writing testable code is also important. Read this article [Writing Testable Code](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/08/by-miko-hevery-so-you-decided-to.html)

Answer (score 0):

No, the way you've implemented the `output()` method there is little you can do to test its logic. If you instead of printing stuff to `System.out` would add it to some list and return that list, you could test the contents of that list to make sure they are what you expect.

The client code (i.e. the code using this method) then becomes responsible for the printing to `System.out`, while the test uses the code to generate some data to verify against.

Instead of

```
public static char[] output() {
    // get input from somewhere
    // print to System.out
}
```

you probably want to do something like

```
public static void reorder(char[] input) {
    char[] output = new char[input.lenght()];
    // reorder the input and put it in output
    return output;
}
```

Then you can test it by doing

```
assertEquals("c,b,a".toCharArray(), m.reorder("a,b,c".toCharArray());
```

Obviously, you'd have to change the usage of your function too, to match the new signature.

Comment: the reorder function has void how come it can return output?

Comment: @user1147717: That was a typo on my side. I meant of course that `output()` should return `char[]`

Answer (score 0):

You should break up your program into smaller parts. I think what you are really trying to test is `sortStringBubble`. So create a test method that calls sortStringBubble with a certain set of characters and then checks that the method did the right thing by checking the result.

If you really wanted to test `output()` (though I'm not sure if there's a lot of value) you could add InputStream/OutputStream parameters to the method. `output` will then read from `InputStream` and write to `OutputStream`. Your test could provide a OutputStream that writes to a string and then you can check the contents of that string when it's done.

Try aiming for tests on a more granular level.